# Which iteration of object I am at

Tags: c++, stdvector, pugixml

I'm currently working with pugi xml, and I frequently use a loop like this:

```
for (pugi::xml_node sth: root.child("name").children())
{
    //do something
}
```

Then at some point I realise that I need to save information at WHICH iteration did I find some value, because it will be needed later, outside of this loop. Can I tell which iteration I am at without adding a counter?

Also if that object was a vector like so:

```
std::vector<type> vtr;
for (std::vector<type>::iterator it = vtr.begin(); it != vtr.end(); ++it)
{
    //which iteration?
}
```

Comment: With vector interators, at least, you can subtract them like `it - vtr.begin()` and get a `vector::difference_type` which is probably a `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: consider using `auto &sth` or even `auto const &sth` in a range-based loop: the way you have it now is taking a copy of each member of the container.

Comment: Nice comment about `&sth`, It hasn't come to mind. So for Pugi, or generally any other class, the iterated-over-class must provide its own "counter" or else there's no way to tell which iteration I am at?

Answer (score 5):

At any given iterator of interest, you can do this

```
auto index = it - vtr.begin();
```

So `vtr.begin()` would be index `0` and then each element increments from there.
Or you can use [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance).

```
auto index = std::distance(vtr.begin(), it)
```

Comment: note, there is no iterator available in the ranged-based for loop

Comment: Correct. That is the blessing, and curse, of those kinds of loops.

Comment: `distance` algorithm takes linear time! The way of subtracting iterators is better here.

Comment: @PengZhang it only takes linear time if there is no random access available (like `std::list`). For `std::vector` subtraction time is constant, `O(1)`.

Comment: @PengZhang "If *it* is a random-access iterator, the function uses `operator-` to calculate this. Otherwise, the function uses the increase operator (`operator++`) repeatedly."